# Suppose $\lim _{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$. Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1}\right)^{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $\lim _{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$. Calculate: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 
 \infty} \left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+1}\right)^{f(x)}$

I figured the limit is $\dfrac{1}{e}$, but I have to prove it using the definition of limit, not sure how. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $$\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1} \right)^{f(x)} = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{f(x)} \right)^{f(x)}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, we can think of the limit as one where $n=f(x)$ and $n\to\infty$. Hence, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}\right)^{f(x)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{1+n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+n}{n}\right)^{-n}=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^{-1}$$

Comment: Is there a general result that if $\lim_{x\to c}f=c$ then $\lim_{x\to c}g=\lim_{f\to c}g$ ? It seems obvious but can't find a source for it.

Comment: I don't think I can just stick the statement about $n$ without explaining it

Comment: I just simply replace $f(x)$ with the symbol $n$. Then since the limit with $f(x)$ has it going to infinity, I take $n$ to infinity. You could do the entire calculation above with $f(x)$, but I use the replacement of $n$ to make the limit look more familiar.

Comment: @Jam it follows pretty quickly just by doing $\epsilon-\delta$ stuff.

Comment: The important point to note here is that $n$ is a real variable and the limit $(1+n^{-1})^{n}\to e$ is well known (it is a much stronger result than the case when $n$ is a positive integer), so the result in question follows by putting $n=f(x) $.

Answer (score 2):

1. You seem to know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^x=\frac1e$.
2. Therefore, you know that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $M_\varepsilon$ such that for all $y>M_\varepsilon$, $\left\lvert\frac1e-\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)^y\right\rvert<\varepsilon$.
3. You also know by hypothesis that for all $M$ there is $x_M$ such that for all $x>x_M$, $f(x)>M$.
4. Finally, for each $\varepsilon>0$ you *want* $N_\varepsilon$ such that for all $x>N_\varepsilon$, $\left\lvert\frac1e-\left(\frac {f(x)}{1+f(x)}\right)^{f(x)}\right\rvert<\varepsilon$.

A good candidate should be $N_\varepsilon=x_{M_{\varepsilon}}$: for $x>x_{M_\varepsilon}$, $f(x)>M_\varepsilon$ by $(3)$. And, by $(2)$, you have what you want.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \left( \frac { f(x) }{ f(x)+1 }  \right) ^{ f(x) }=\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ f(x)+1 }  \right) ^{ f(x) }=\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left[ { \left( 1+\frac { -1 }{ f(x)+1 }  \right)  }^{ -\left( f\left( x \right) +1 \right)  } \right]  } ^{ -\frac { f\left( x \right)  }{ 1+f\left( x \right)  }  }={ e }^{ \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { -f\left( x \right) }{ f\left( x \right)+1 }  }  }=\frac { 1 }{ e } $$

Comment: I need to somehow eliminate the f(x) to prove this properly I think.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=f(x)$. Then $u \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, and
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+1}\right)^{f(x)}
= \lim_{u \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{u}{u+1}\right)^{u}
= \lim_{u \to \infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{u+1}\right)^{u} \\
= \lim_{u \to \infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{u+1}\right)^{u+1} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{u+1}\right)^{-1}
= e^{-1} \cdot 1 = e^{-1}
$$